# How to make `Map::get` return either an `Optional` of the found value or `Optional.empty()`

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm trying to do this:

```
return Optional.of(myMap.getOrDefault(myKey, null));
```

Really, what I want is to return an `Optional.of(foundVal)` if found, otherwise `Optional.empty()`. I don't believe `Optional.of(null)` equates to that. What syntax does what I want to do?

That is, how can I get a map `get` to return a proper `Optional`?

Comment: `Optional#ofNullable`, or better yet you can do some actions if the key is absent e.g. `Map#computeIfAbsent`

Comment: but think of that null a little, `null` might mean value not present or key *actually* mapped to null, depends of your map and application

Comment: @Eugene - Thanks. Yup, I am constructing the map myself from a stream so if the value doesn't exist then the entry would never have existed either. Still, I'm trying to cover all null cases.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get(myKey));
```

[JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable-T-)

Answer (score 17):

This

```
Optional.of(myMap.getOrDefault(myKey, null));
```

or really

```
Optional.of(null);
```

would've failed with a `NullPointerException`. As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of(T)) states

> Throws:
>   **NullPointerException** - if `value` is null

[`Optional#ofNullable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ofNullable(T)) exists when you don't know if the value you're passing to it is `null` or not:

> **Parameters**:
>   `value` - the possibly-null value to describe

And since [`Map#get(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) already returns `null` when there is no entry for the given key

> **Returns**:
>   the value to which the specified key is mapped, or `null` if
>   this map contains no mapping for the key

you don't need to use `getOrDefault` with a `null` value for the default. You can instead directly use

```
Optional.ofNullable(myMap.get(myKey));
```

Answer (score -2):

If the map contains a null value, the `Optional.ofNullable(...)` solution won't work. You need to do something like:

```java
myMap.containsKey(myKey) ? Optional.of(myMap.get(myKey)) : Optional.empty();
```

It's annoying to have to check the map twice, but there doesn't seem to be a better way.

Comment: If the map contains a `null` value that you want to treat as non-empty `Optional`, then this pattern will not work anyway, as `Optional.of(null)` will throw an exception. You can use some kind of [NULL object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead of `null` reference to put it into the `Optional`, but in this case it's better to put it into the `Map` in the first place, and then `Optional.ofNullable(...)` will work fine.

Answer (score -7):

Functional and definitely too long solution:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(it -> it.getKey().equals(myKey))
  .findFirst()
  .map(Map.Entry::getValue);
```

Comment: very bad idea as this does not leverage the map's index and do a full map scan